# how to get an element by Web Scraping a website

Tags: python, html, spring-boot, selenium, web-scraping

the Web page i'm scraping form is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>... </head>
<body>
  <div>... </div>
  <div>... </div>
  <div>... </div>
  <script>... </script>
  <form name="rCCSearchForm" method="post" action="/search/RCCSearch.do">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="central-content-old">
          <div class="static-page-container">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>...</tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>..</td>
                  <td>
                    <table class="tbl-measurement">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>...</tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>"name"</td>
                          <td>...</td>
                          <td>...</td>
                          <td>...</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
.........
```

i want to get the name in the elements using either selenium.webdriver in python or anything that can be integrated in spring boot like the jsoup library...

Comment: Please try it yourself first. There are [tutorials](https://google.com/?q=selenium+tutorial) and the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: i added my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020227/getting-an-element-by-web-scraping-a-website

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `selenium`. Install selenium by `pip install selenium` & download `Firefox or Chrome driver`. You can refer documentation to get started & get the text by,

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_of_element').text)
```

Comment: can you tell me what the xpath_of_element is?

Comment: This is a place holder for an XPATH selector. I strongly urge you to learn abit about XPATH selectors for this question. The find_element_by_xpath, is the way to find HTML attributes/text but it requires the understanding of XPATH.